# How to store the value of and input inside a button using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I just started learning javascript. What I want to do is store the value of an input after I press "Save" inside a button using `localStorage` and change its name. Thanks.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnURX.jpg)

```
<h3 id="titlu" class="bh">Chat</h3>
<input type="button" name="userName" id="Uname" class="Uname" value="Username"/>
<div id="popUp">
    <p>Set your username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="setusername" id="userSet">
    <input type="button" id="save" class="pophide" name="save" value="save"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var valoare = $("#userSet").val();
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            // Store
            localStorage.user = valoare;
            // Retrieve
            document.getElementById("Uname").innerHTML = localStorage.user;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Uname").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
       }
    });
})
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Thx i know about that w3school , i just cant figure it out , i quess my brain is zero . Ty tho .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is generally fine. The only real problem I can see is how you are setting the text at the end.

As `Uname` is an `<input type="button">`, you use it in a similar way to `<input type="text">`. To change the text displayed, you need to set it's `value` property, not `innerHTML`.

As you are using jQuery, you can use `val()` as you did to read the input value earlier:

```
$("#Uname").val(localStorage.user);
```

A second small point. It is generally fine to use `localStorage.user`, but it is safer to use the standard calls, [`setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to avoid conflicting with an existing property of the `Storage` object, e.g. `localStorage.setItem = 'My Set Item'` will cause you problems.

The following should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // display previous stored username, if set
    var prevUname = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if(prevUname !== null) {
        $("#Uname").val(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    }

    $("#save").click(function(){
        var valoare = $("#userSet").val();
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("user", valoare);

            // Retrieve
            $("#Uname").val(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        } else {
            $("#Uname").val("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
       }
    });
})
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rhumborl/wyhaLtfL/)

Comment: Your a life saver :D Thank You , another thing if you may , If the user have never been on the page , i want him to see the value of the button as Username before he types something and saves it inside. Hope you understand what i wrote. Thanks again :).

Comment: No problem. You just need to check if the first `localStorage.getItem("user")` is null or not. Have updated the code to handle this.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . Cheers